# Creating Subnet IP address : IPv4 block sizes must be between a /16 netmask and /28 netmask

Tags: amazon-web-services, iptables, linux-networking, subnet, amazon-vpc

I'm new to AWS and I'm looking to create a subnet. Whenever I try the defaults subnets under I get either the error message "IPv4 block sizes must be between a /16 netmask and /28 netmask." or "CIDR Address is not within CIDR Address from VPC."[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBoFg.png)

I'm not sure how to proceed. Please can anyone assist.
Thank you

Comment: As mentioned, a VPC will have a large address space that is divided up in to smaller, non-overlapping subnets, often associated with different availability zones. You need to obtain a basic understanding of subnetting.

Answer (score 1):

The image attached has the answer. You've already defined a huge subnet 172.31.0.0/20 the second subnet you tried to create 172.31.0.0/16 falls within that. You probably got VPC and subnets confused. A VPC (virtual private cloud aka virtual network) has many subnets, which can't overlap.

I suggest you delete all your subnets and create some /24 subnets, rather than /20 subnets.

Comment: When I do that I still get the error message

Comment: Please edit your question to show screenshots of your VPC (including CIDR) and your subnets (including CIDR) then comment below so I get a notification.